# If $n\geq 6$ natural number then $\exists p,q\leq n-1$ prime number such that : $(n-q,n-p)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Question :

Prove that for every even integer greater than $6$ there exist two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that : 
$p$ and $q$ are less than $n-1$ and $n-p$ and $n-q$ are relatively prime

I don't know how I starte ? To prove that !

Can give me some ideas to approach ?

Comment: You have $\le$ in the title, not $\gt$ or $\ge$.  The title also does not include "even"

Comment: Yes sir @Ross Millikan sorry!! Thanks!

Comment: @EllenEllen Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly ? As stated, $p=2, q=3$ seems to be a solution for any $n \ge 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be even and $q=3,p=5$.  Then $(n-p,n-q)=(n-3,n-5)=(2,n-5)=1$  This is the same idea as in the comment by gandalf61, which came in while I was writing this.

Comment: One should not write "is just...". Rather, one should give an argument proving that the claimed equivalence holds true (esp. at this level).

Comment: Can you expand on the connection with Goldbach ? The problem doesn't say that $n-p$ and $n-q$ are prime, only that they are *relatively* prime i.e. $\gcd(n-p,n-q)=1$.